# Using the Chern–Gauss–Bonnet theorem to calculate the hypervolume of a spherical simplex

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spherical-geometry

The area formula for a spherical triangle is often stated as a consequence of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem:
$$\int_MKdA+\int_{\partial M}k_gds=2\pi\chi(M)$$
The idea is that in a spherical triangle $T$ on the unit sphere, all of the geodesic curvature is contained in the vertices, so
$$\int_TdA+\sum\alpha=2\pi$$
where we sum over the turning angles (exterior angles) $\alpha$ of the vertices. Rearranging and stating in terms of interior angles $\alpha'=\pi-\alpha$,
$$A(T)=\pi-\sum \alpha'$$

I was wondering how this method could be generalized to higher dimensions with the [Chern-Gauss-Bonnet (CGB) theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem). In particular **I would like to derive the hypervolume formula for a spherical $2n$-simplex on $S^{2n}$ with the CGB theorem in terms of its interior solid angles**. I believe the form of the CGB theorem we want is Theorem II in [this paper](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/allenweil.pdf) by Allendoerfer and Weil, which is a generalization to Riemannian polyhedra. However, I don't have great knowledge of differential geometry so I can't exactly see how Theorem II should simplify in the case of a spherical simplex.